# Text on the side

Tags: listings, marginpar, marginnote

I need to put text on the left side from my lst listing it should look like on the photo.

```
\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{
   belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
   breaklines=true,
   frame=none,
   numbers=none,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{gray!120!white},
   commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
   identifierstyle=\color{black},
   backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10!white},
   language=Python
}
\lstset{style=myStyle}

\begin{lstlisting}
from IPython import parallel
engines = parallel.Client()
engines.block = True
print engines.ids \end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: Right, but where's the code you already wrote?

Comment: This is what i wrote so far

Comment: \lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=none,
    numbers=none, 
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{gray!120!white},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10!white},
    language=Python,
}
\lstset{style=myStyle}
\begin{lstlisting}
from IPython import parallel
engines = parallel.Client()
engines.block = True
print engines.ids
\end{lstlisting}

Comment: Thanks for your edit. As a general rule on Tex-SE, it's appreciated when you post a complete Minimum Working Example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so that everyone can just copy/paste your code and test it without having to figure out what packages or libraries you're using. Keep that in mind for the future and welcome.

Comment: You might check out tcblisting (tcolorbox package).  Putting things into margins typically involves things like \marginpar or \llap, but verbatim like environments do their own formatting.  \tikz[overlay,remember picture} outside the listing is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\parskip=3pt
\parindent=0pt
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
We have seen how to initialize the cluster. No matter which way we
initialize the cluster, the following commands allow us to connect to
it. These commands should either be introduced through the notebook or
typed into the IPython command line interpreter (the client):

{\ttfamily
  from IPython import parallel\marginnote{In[1]:}\newline
  engines = parallel.Client()\newline
  engines.block = True\newline
  print engines.ids\newline

  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]\marginnote{Out[1]:}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for this but is there any chance to do it with lst lists? If there is no way than thanks for your solution

Comment: You should use `\ttfamily` instead of `\tt`.